# Open Debugger tools via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create my own context menu that changes depending on where I click on the screen.

However I don't want to lose the easy access to chrome dev tools via `right click > inspect`. Ideally I want to add my own entry that only appears if I compile the program in `DEBUG`.

Can this be done? Or is it prevented to avoid websites being annoying?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: You can't do this.  Also, I'd suggest *not* using  custom right click menu in the first place, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @CodeLover: How does that link help here?  He wants to programmatically open the dev tools window from inside his code.

Comment: alternate solution: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of replacing browser's contextmenu with yours, you could add entries to it, so you won't lose "Inspect" command.

To do that, you can use HTML5 `<menu>`.

You can read a tutorial here: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-context-menu

```
<section contextmenu="mymenu">
    <!-- Content -->
</section>

<menu type="context" id="mymenu">
    <menuitem label="Refresh Post" onclick="window.location.reload();" icon="/images/refresh-icon.png"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Skip to Comments" onclick="window.location='#comments';" icon="/images/comment_icon.gif"></menuitem>
    <menu label="Share on..." icon="/images/share_icon.gif">
        <menuitem label="Twitter" icon="/images/twitter_icon.gif" onclick="goTo('//twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + document.title + ':  ' + window.location.href);"></menuitem>
        <menuitem label="Facebook" icon="/images/facebook_icon16x16.gif" onclick="goTo('//facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + window.location.href);"></menuitem>
    </menu>
</menu>
```

But be aware that it is not widely supported.